# How to save/ load game data for webGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've used playerprefs and also added serialization,  everything works but i need another way of saving and loading because i have the game on a website, and on the site, there's a login, i need to find out if there is a way to save data to a persons account and also be able to load the data back into the game when the person logs in , even from a different pc

Comment: You can use a database and make you game make rest call or use an web-service with the back-end server.
If you are putting your game in a game-specific web-site like Kongregate you should give a look if the site don't have an API where you can store players data.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this. You can write your own server side code, or use a third party plugin to accomplish this.

If you're interested in trying your own implementation, [Unity Wiki's Server Side Highscore](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Server_Side_Highscores) is an excellent starting point.

The example contains a step-wise explanation on how to setup your database, some PHP code (which allows you to GET & POST) and Unity side code in both JS & C#.

Comment: I have to use c#, it's for a project for one of my modules

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I have created a server for writing data on server for my webGL game in unity. Here is path of [git repository](https://github.com/neervfx/server/tree/master).

Comment: I have to use c# , it's for a project in university , is there a way? I have different difficulties aswell,  so will i be able to load the information and difficulty of the game or would that be too complex

Comment: Class is written in c# only. Sample class has all the functions and instructions required to save and load game data online from server.